# Gravity in 2d games(360 degrees)

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

Hello all I am trying to make a game with the Phaser game engine and would like to implement some sort of 360 gravity. Essentially I just want the player to be able to rotate around the sphere. I was wondering what would be the best way to do this in phaser. I know that you can set objects gravities but you can only do so in the x and y direction. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you should use the concept of vectors for this.

like you want as a planet attracts towards another sun in a orbit.

then define
  `function Vector(x, y){
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
}`

and these are pseudo codes
get acceleration vector direction by
`vector(sun.position.x-planet.position.x,sun.position.y-planet.position.y)`

then
`planet.velocity.x+=acceleration.x 
planet.velocity.y+=acceleration.y`

for further using vector you can try
http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html